# How to test analyzer-smartcn plugin for Elastic Search on local machine

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed the smartcn plugin on my elastic search, restarted elasticsearch and tried to create an index with these settings:

```
PUT /test_chinese
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "default": {
            "type": "smartcn"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run this in Marvel, I get this error back and I see a bunch of errors in Elastic search:

> "error": "IndexCreationException[[test_chinese] failed to create
>   index]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find
>   analyzer type [smartcn] or tokenizer for [default]]; nested:
>   NoClassSettingsException[Failed to load class setting [type] with
>   value [smartcn]]; nested:
>   ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.smartcn.SmartcnAnalyzerProvider];
>   ",    "status": 400

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Are you sure smartcn installed successfully? Try GET /_cat/plugins to see if analysis-smartcn is listed

Comment: Ahh, it isn't there. I did install it to my elastic search folder by way of here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/installation.html

it appears when i run plugins.bat -l but when i run it on the server it's not there. From my knowledge, I just have to restart Elastic Search after installing the plugin so I'm not sure why it isn't getting to my nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I manually installed the plugins from the zip and it was causing issues... I reinstalled the right way but specific to 1.7 and it worked